# How to make this graph in R

Tags: r, graph, sankey-diagram

Do you know what this kind of graph is called, and how can I make it in R?

Thanks-

[image]

Source of the image: http://www.wired.com/2014/05/alumni-network-2/

Comment: [**This post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968433/sankey-diagrams-in-r) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Also: http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualizing-website-pathing-with-sankey-charts/

I think ggvis may be a good route. Some have gotten Sankey + Shiny (R) to work. That be something you are interested in! https://github.com/adomasb/sankeyNshiny/issues/1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this chart is called a 'Sankey diagram'. I don't really know how to do in R but I am using d3 to create this at work. An example here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/