# How generate a graph showing behaviour of users?

Tags: graph, plot, statistics, tracking, usage-statistics

I'd like to find out more about the behaviour of users in a login area. therefore I store each action a user does. Example:

```
User1: (main page) -> (login) -> (view posts) -> (view page of user) -> (logout)
User2: (main page) -> (login) -> (view posts) -> (write post) -> (logout)
User3: (main page) -> (login) -> (view settings) -> (change password) -> (logout)
```

Now I'd like to display the behaviours in a graph. Hereby the edges should reflect the frequency:

```
                                       (write post) - (logout)
                                     /
(main-page) ≡ (login) = (view posts) - (view page of user) - (logout)
                      \
                        (view settings) - (change password) - (logout)
```

What are typical tools to accomplish this task? And is there a typical data format that my tools should generate? Would be great to have a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Sankey digagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) could do the job. There a [several tools](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24074/whats-a-good-tool-to-create-sankey-diagrams) you can use.

To me [using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968433/sankey-diagrams-in-r) and [googlevis](http://www.magesblog.com/2014/03/sankey-diagrams-with-googlevis.html) seem to be straight forward.