# Sankey bar graphs in R

Tags: graphics, sankey-diagram

I'd like to make this type of plot in R.

[image: sankey bar graph made in SAS]

There's more detail on the SAS macros to produce this example here: http://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2015/DV/PharmaSUG-2015-DV07.pdf

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I should go about doing this in R?

NOTE: I know how to make standard sankey diagrams with the D3 or google libraries. This question is specifically about the combination of bar graph and sankey diagram that the SAS macros produce.

Comment: You may need to do an overlay (using `par(new = TRUE)`) with [`SankeyR`](https://gist.github.com/aaronberdanier/1423501) and a regular barplot. Here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968433/sankey-diagrams-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Use the library(flipPlots), using the SankeyDiagram() function.