# Replicating a Data Visualization with R/ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Replicating a visualization I saw in print media using `ggplot2`

**Context**:
I am always looking to make data visualizations more appealing/aesthetic specifically for non-data people, who are the majority of people I work with (stakeholders like marketers, management, etc) -- I've noted that when visualizations look like academic-publication-quality (standard `ggplot2` aesthetics) they tend to assume they *can't* understand it and don't bother trying, defeating the whole purpose of visualizations in the first place. However, when it looks more graphic'y (like something you may see on websites or marketing material) they focus and try to understand the visualization, usually successfully.  Often we'll end up in the most interesting discussions from these types of visualizations, so that is my ultimate goal.

**The Visualization**:
[image: The vis I'd like to replicate in R/ggplot2]

Here is something I saw on some marketing brochure on the device share of web traffic by geo, and though it is actually a bit busy and unclear, it resonated better than a similar stacked bar chart I created in standard -- I have not the slightest idea how I might replicate something like this within `ggplot2`, any attempts would be much appreciated! Here is some sample tidy data to use in a `data.table`:

```
structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                       "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Canada",
                       "Canada", "Canada", "China", "China",
                       "China", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Spain",
                       "Spain", "Spain", "UK", "UK", "UK", "USA",
                       "USA", "USA"), 
           device_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                     3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                     1L, 2L, 3L), 
                                   class = "factor", 
                                   .Label = c("desktop", 
                                              "mobile", 
                                              "multi")), 
           proportion = c(0.37, 0.22, 0.41, 0.3, 0.31, 0.39, 
                          0.35, 0.06, 0.59, 0.19, 0.2, 0.61, 
                          0.4, 0.18, 0.42, 0.16, 0.28, 0.56, 
                          0.27, 0.06, 0.67, 0.37, 0.08, 0.55)),
      .Names = c("country", "device_type", "proportion"), 
      row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
      class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also consider `googleVis`

```
library(googleVis)

dat <- structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                           "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Canada",
                           "Canada", "Canada", "China", "China",
                           "China", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Spain",
                           "Spain", "Spain", "UK", "UK", "UK", "USA",
                           "USA", "USA"), 
               device_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 3L), 
                                       class = "factor", 
                                       .Label = c("desktop", 
                                                  "mobile", 
                                                  "multi")), 
               proportion = c(0.37, 0.22, 0.41, 0.3, 0.31, 0.39, 
                              0.35, 0.06, 0.59, 0.19, 0.2, 0.61, 
                              0.4, 0.18, 0.42, 0.16, 0.28, 0.56, 
                              0.27, 0.06, 0.67, 0.37, 0.08, 0.55)),
          .Names = c("country", "device_type", "proportion"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

link_order <- unique(dat$country)
node_order <- unique(as.vector(rbind(dat$country, as.character(dat$device_type))))

link_cols <- data.frame(color = c('#ffd1ab', '#ff8d14', '#ff717e', '#dd2c40', '#d6b0ea', 
                        '#8c4fab','#00addb','#297cbe'), 
                        country = c("UK", "Canada", "USA", "China", "Spain", "Japan", "Argentina", "Brazil"),
                        stringsAsFactors = F)

node_cols <- data.frame(color = c("#ffc796", "#ff7100", "#ff485b", "#d20000", 
                                  "#cc98e6", "#6f2296", "#009bd2", "#005daf", 
                                  "grey", "grey", "grey"),
                        type = c("UK", "Canada", "USA", "China", "Spain", "Japan", 
                                 "Argentina", "Brazil", "multi", "desktop", "mobile"))

link_cols2 <- sapply(link_order, function(x) link_cols[x == link_cols$country, "color"])
node_cols2 <- sapply(node_order, function(x) node_cols[x == node_cols$type, "color"])

actual_link_cols <- paste0("[", paste0("'", link_cols2,"'", collapse = ','), "]")
actual_node_cols <- paste0("[", paste0("'", node_cols2,"'", collapse = ','), "]")

opts <- paste0("{
        link: { colorMode: 'source',
               colors: ", actual_link_cols ," },
        node: {colors: ", actual_node_cols ,"}}")

Sankey <- gvisSankey(dat, 
                     from = "country", 
                     to = "device_type", 
                     weight = "proportion",
                     options = list(height = 500, width = 1000, sankey = opts))


plot(Sankey)
```

[image]

Comment: this is absolutely gorgeous! how would the code need to be modified to accommodate a multi-level sankey?

Comment: @tangerine7199 you basically have to define more links (in this case - mobile to ? and desktop to ? etc)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with "ggalluvial" package and its respective "geom".

[Chek this out](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/ggalluvial.html)

Comment: Ah this was it - Alluvial & Sankey diagrams .. After your link above I found what I was looking for in full detail (including `ggaluvial`) right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968433/sankey-diagrams-in-r)