# ggforce in R to create sankey diagram with NA values and geom_parallel_sets

Tags: r, nodes, sankey-diagram, ggforce

My goal is to create a Sankey diagram that has each column of nodes parallel to each other and not by default nodes that aren't aligned with the next column(s). I posted asking for help but I have not received an answer: [geom_sankey in R: spacing and aligning nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442590/geom-sankey-in-r-spacing-and-aligning-nodes).

Here is the output of my attempt using `geom_sankey`and the issues with it:
[image]

This post: [Sankey diagram in R: How to change the height (Y) of individual sections related to each node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083945/sankey-diagram-in-r-how-to-change-the-height-y-of-individual-sections-related) has me convinced that I am going about this the wrong way and that I should try the `ggforce` package.

The crux of the issue: I cannot figure out how to format the data so that `ggplot`'s flag of `split` and the `fill` flag of `geom_parallel_sets` is satisfied with the data that I am using. Here is a made up example, but my data is of a similar 'flavor.'

**Example**

#Making df

```
Years <- data.frame(Earlier = c(rep(2012, 2), paste(2013), paste(2014), rep(2015, 2), rep(2018, 2), rep(2022, 2), rep(NA, 31)),
           Latest = c(rep(2023, 4), rep(2022, 6), rep(2021, 10), rep(2020, 3), rep(2019, 6), rep(2018, 3), rep(2017, 3), rep(2013, 4), rep(NA, 2)),
           Current = c(rep(2023, 10), rep(2022, 12), rep(2021, 11), rep(2020, 1), rep(NA, 7)))
```

#Shuffling

```
set.seed(123)
Years[sample(1:nrow(Years)), ]
```

#Changing all data.frame to numeric

```
ix <- 1:3
Years[ix] <- lapply(Years[ix], as.numeric)
```

#putting it in `ggforce` format

```
Years2 <- gather_set_data(Years, 1:3)
```

This gives the following output (1st 10 rows)

[image]

According to the posts (like the one I linked above) doing sankey's with `ggforce`, I need to fulfill the `split` and `fill` flags, but as you can see, splitting by column x will not give me the desired output. Additionally, I would like to `fill` by the years, with each year having it's unique color and I also would like the column names to appear on the graph, like the image above.

Here is the code I am using and I am putting ??? where I am stuck.

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggforce)

ggplot(Years2, 
       aes(x = x, id = id, split = ???, value = ???)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = ???), alpha = 0.3, 
                     axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = "white", 
                            angle = 0, size = 3,
                            axis.width = aw, sep = sp) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I have tried many, many things - some notable efforts include: adding another column called 'split' on the Years2 df and pasting a 1,2,3 for when the 'Earlier', 'Latest', and 'Current' numbers start turning to NA's; using the `melt` function from `reshape2`, and using the `Years %>% make_long(Earlier, Latest, Current)` command needed for the `geom_sankey` command.

Extra info: sessionInfo() R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit) Running under: macOS Ventura 13.6

**Any help navigating this quagmire would be greatly appreciated. Thank-you.**

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. According to the [documentation](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_parallel_sets.html), `geom_parallel_sets` require `value` to be provided as an aesthetic. I assume the `value` represent frequency of connections between nodes (or the thickness of links). You may get these counts using `table` and `reshape2::melt()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

# data
Years <- data.frame(Earlier = c(rep(2012, 2), paste(2013), paste(2014), rep(2015, 2), rep(2018, 2), rep(2022, 2), rep(NA, 31)),
                    Latest = c(rep(2023, 4), rep(2022, 6), rep(2021, 10), rep(2020, 3), rep(2019, 6), rep(2018, 3), rep(2017, 3), rep(2013, 4), rep(NA, 2)),
                    Current = c(rep(2023, 10), rep(2022, 12), rep(2021, 11), rep(2020, 1), rep(NA, 7)))


# format data for sankey diagram
df <- table(Years) |> 
  reshape2::melt() |> 
  gather_set_data(1:3)

# plot
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(color = "white", angle = 0,
                            axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. However, this is not what I’m looking for. I am looking for the graph image that I posted above - it’s just that using  ‘geom_sankey’ squishes my first column together and places the boxes of that 1st column (Earlier) below the other two columns. 

I need the column names to show for each column  (e.g., Ealier, Latest, Current) and the flow between them and splitting by “x” or “y” isn’t giving this. It’s a data formatting issue and I can’t seem to figure out the proper format for this data with ‘ggforce’ so the graph can visually resemble this one.

Comment: @Purrsia does your graph need to be in `ggforce`? I'm afraid `ggforce` might not be the one that can meet your requirement. I think `geom_parallel_sets` expects all three columns to have non-missing values. The problem arises with the column Earlier having missing values. Given this data `library(dplyr);  df <- Years %>%    count(Earlier, Latest, Current) %>%    mutate(row_sum = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%    filter(row_sum < 2) %>%    gather_set_data(1:3)`, my attempt at creating a plot threw the following error:

Comment: error message: ``Caused by error in `compute_panel()`:
! Axis aesthetics must be constant in each split ``. The `split` argument has to have non-missing values.

Comment: The code I tried to create a sankey diagram: `df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, id = id, split = y, value = n)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(color = "white", angle = 0,
                            axis.width = 0.1, sep = 0.1)`

Comment: no, the graph does not need to be made in `ggforce`. I want to be able to make a sankey diagram (image posted) with the boxes of the first column higher up (e.g., Earlier) or parallel to the next two columns. I'm willing to try anything. I've tried the `alluvia` package, `geom_sankey` and now `ggforce` to do this. Nothing works!! I am surprised that one cannot change the distance of the boxes. The `geom_sankey` I used in my previous post has a `spacing` flag, but it puts spaces on all boxes across all 3 columns. I just want the first column's boxes to be moved up, really.

Comment: @Purrsia I answered your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77461378/16421247)