# What is the name of this figure?

Tags: r, plot, figure

[image]

I found this kind of figure in many manuscripts.

What is the name of this figure? How to plot in R?

Thanks

Comment: I’ve used this before it’s a sankey diagram. The package is like a widget

Comment: This is Sankey diagram.
I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968433/sankey-diagrams-in-r).